# Plantilla única para todas las páginas con Express js

Tags: html5, nodejs, express

estoy empezando a utilizar expressjs y me preguntaba si hay alguna forma en la que pueda utilizar una única plantilla html para `<navbar>`, `<footer>`, `<sidebar>`, etc. y que dentro de ésta se ubique el contenido, algo parecido a lo que se usa en flask con extend y block, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Puedes usar [ejs](https://ejs.co) es muy sencillo de utilizar

Comment: O tambien [`pug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug), o quien quita [`handlebars`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) o incluso [`mustache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache). Y ese es el problema con tu pregunta, se basa en opiniones. Te invito a leer [ask]. Saludos